# Is it a good practice to browse for questions and upvote the answers which are really good even if they already have upvotes?

Tags: discussion, answers, up-votes

I am thinking if this practice would help the really good answers stand out even more and maybe people would be helped by this by having the high vote answers stand out.

Comment: I believe that this is the entire point of allowing upvotes at all...

Answer (score 9):

Go ahead. There's nothing wrong with this.

Just one caveat - don't go through posts by specific people and vote on just their stuff. That would be considered serial voting - the system will detect and reverse such votes (the idea is that one is supposed to vote for posts, not people).